# How to add items to a unordered list <ul> using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

In my json response, I want to loop through it using $.each and then append items to a `<ul></ul>` element.

```
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {

        // item.UserID
        // item.Username

     }
```

I want to add a

, and create a href tag that links to the users page.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The most efficient way is to create an array and append to the dom once.

You can make it better still by losing all the string concat from the string. Either push multiple times to the array or build the string using += and then push but it becomes a bit harder to read for some.

Also you can wrap all the items in a parent element (in this case the ul) and append that to the container for best performance. Just push the '`<ul>'` and `'</ul>'` before and after the each and append to a div.

```js
data = [
{
  "userId": 1,
  "Username": "User_1"
},
{
  "userId": 2,
  "Username": "User_2"
}
];

var items = [];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {

  items.push('<li><a href="yourlink?id=' + item.UserID + '">' + item.Username + '</a></li>');

}); // close each()

$('#yourUl').append(items.join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="yourUl">
</ul>
```

Comment: i like this idea, one append.

Comment: Does this have injection issues like another comment stated?

Comment: Do you trust your source? Do you have control over the json or is it from a third party? What do the links do. Can they delete from the links? Lots of good articles on google. Start with this one http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/10/json-and-browser-security/

Comment: I am the source, so I trust myself :)

Comment: In jQuery 1.4.3 you have a new thing called "tmpl". It's worth the look: http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/

Comment: @Nordes - yeah - this was well before 1.4.3!

Comment: @redsquare This is now a part of the API (see the comment on the JQuery page : version added: 1.4.3)

Comment: @Nordes.......eh? This answer was from Jul 2009. I know .tmpl is part of 1.4.3 but cannot go through and amend all jquery answers in support of this!

Comment: should really be `items.join("")` otherwise commas will be put between `<li>` items. Otherwise very handy solution!

Comment: Good stuff!  One thing, I think you need a ); at the end of your each.

Comment: @mrblah Yes, this method does have injection issues.  It doesn't matter what the data source is, at a minimum you risk creating invalid ambiguous HTML.  In fact, in this case there are two problems.  Not only is the variable data not escaped for the HTML, but the ID is not encoded for use in a URL.  In a happy-path world, your ID will never contain characters that are reserved, and your usernames will not contain characters that must be replaced with entity references.  Realistically, code like this should be completely transparent so you never have to worry about it.

Comment: if you wrap your html variables in push in `\`<a>\`` instead of `'<a>'` or `"<a>"` you can have multiline variables which is critical for writing html into javascript files in terms of being able to read or edit your code in the future.

Answer (score 7):

I decided to take redsquare's excellent answer and improve upon it a bit.  Rather than adding HTML, I prefer to add jQuery objects.  That way, I don't have to worry about escaping for HTML and what not.

In this example, `data` contains an array of objects, parsed from JSON.  Each object in the array has a `.title` property.  I use jQuery's `each` function to loop through them.

```
var items=[];
$(data).each(function(index, Element) {
    items.push($('<li/>').text(Element.title));
});
$('#my_list').append.apply($('#my_list'), items);
```

I push a new jQuery object onto the items array, but with method chaining I can set properties ahead of time, such as `.text`.

I then append the array of objects to the list `<ul id="my_list">` using [Lars Gersmann's method](http://orangevolt.blogspot.com/2009/04/howto-use-jquery-append-with-array.html).

Answer (score 6):

Get the `<ul>` using jQuery selector syntax and then call `append`:

```
$("ul#theList").append("<li><a href='url-here'>Link Text</a></li>");
```

See [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content) for more information.

Comment: if you have the id use it alone. Dont prefix the nodeName, slower.

Comment: Yeah I know, I was just trying to be expressive here since no ID was provided in the question.

Comment: Fair enough, but I see the same things all over here & the web. Spread the word:)

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {

       var li = $("<li><a></a></li>");

       $("#yourul").append(li);

       $("a",li).text(item.Username);
       $("a",li).attr("href", "http://example.com" + item.UserID);

    }
```

Comment: Take care to properly encode the data use din the URL.  `encodeURIComponent`