# How to add to TOP of unordered list with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've created a Facebook/Twitter like status update and can add the new status to an element. I recently found a great article that explains "[How to add items to an unordered list using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208467/how-to-add-items-to-a-unordered-list-ul-using-jquery)" but I'm not skilled enough to edit it to make it add to the TOP of my unordered list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [prepend](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend#content) method instead of append.