# Adding to database using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have an  undordered list

- Aditya
- Sam

which contains the names of people from a table. Now I am adding another name to the database using ajax .The names get inserted properly in the database, but I have to refresh the page  to see the changes(which is certainly not wanted).

This part confuses me.

1)If I return a response to javascript which gives the "Name" and I add a list element "Name" to the dom.Then on page refresh, that element is not found on the page.

2)If i do not return a response and just add to database , then i have to refresh the page to see the changes.

I am using plain javascript based ajax call , not using jquery etc.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: when you return a response with the name, are you still adding it to the database first?

Comment: lets see the php that handles the database entry and response.

Comment: @dqhendricks . Yes I am adding it to the database first.

Comment: but in method two, when you refresh, the item shows up? this is bizzar. please edit your code and show us the php that updates the database and returns the response to ajax.

Comment: @dqhendricks. This is what confuses me .I have two functions one which pulls all the names from the database and is used to display names on the page. Another which updates the database.Now once I update the database , the first fuction should pull up the record and dsiplay on the page. Do i still need to send a response ?

Comment: yes, if you want the item to be added without refreshing. like i said though, we need to see code to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @dqhendricks Solved the issue . Returning a response<li></li> which appends the elements of the unordered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using plain javascript based ajax
>   call , not using jquery etc.

You should learn to use [xmlhttprequest](http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html) if you want to do it without jquery(or any other kind of framework). You should also learn to [append text/html to an element](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2279811/DOM-Append-Text-and-Elements-With-Javascript). Basically you will need to learn javascript the old fashion way, but keep in mind only to use the "[good parts of javascript](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748)".

But in my opinion you should use jquery instead(have not heard compelling reason why you are not using it) because that will make javascript development a lot easier. You can achieve this easily by using:

1. use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ to add item to the database.
2. next [add item to unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208467/how-to-add-items-to-a-unordered-list-ul-using-jquery) using jquery.