# Whats the proper syntax to append a list with multiple classes to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm attempting to append a `li` to a class with multiple classes in the `li`.

So my HTML code is :

```
<div class="maincontent">
   <ul>

    <div class="content">

    <div>

   </ul>
</div>
```

And jQuery :

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
    $.each(data, function(n, newData) {
      $(".content")
        .append("<li class='my-li-class'>")
        .append("<div class='imageclass'><img src='"+newData.img+"' class='innerimageclass'></div>")
        .append("<div class='another-inner-div'>")  
        .append("<div class='main-title'>"+newData.title+"</div>")  
        .append("</div>")   
        .append("</li>");
    });
});
```

I'm reading the data from the json. The json data is fine. I can show the data correctly if i use only 1 append and add the entire code in it. But the code looks very bad. So i want to break it down to each line to look nice. Im doing something wrong with the append. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208467/how-to-add-items-to-a-unordered-list-ul-using-jquery

Comment: `div` is not a valid child of `ul`

Comment: Please note: It is *significantly* faster to append multiple items as a single string, than to append multiple items one at a time. You need to rework your code to create a single HTML string and append once at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending `<li>` doesn't append an HTML string, it appends a new element, that opens and closes. So your divs aren't inside the list items. Since you have the whole HTML tree, just `.append()` it all at once:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
    $.each(data, function(n, newData) {
      $(".content").append(
        "<li class='my-li-class'>" + 
        "<div class='imageclass'><img src='"+newData.img+"' class='innerimageclass'></div>" + 
        "<div class='another-inner-div'>" + 
        "<div class='main-title'>"+newData.title+"</div>" +
        "</div>" +  
        "</li>");
    });
});
```

Comment: If I use .html it shows only 1 result. I need to show all the results. So im using append. And thanks a ton. It worked. I was using the plus sign after and before the code for each line. Guess i need to use it once once.

Comment: Correct, i fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When we append an element, it get added to DOM tree so if we check your code,

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
    $.each(data, function(n, newData) {
      $(".content")
        .append("<li class='my-li-class'>")
        .append("<div class='imageclass'><img src='"+newData.img+"' class='innerimageclass'></div>")
        ....
    });
});
```

The time you did

```
$(".content")
        .append("<li class='my-li-class'>")
```

HTML got changed to

```
<div class="content">
    <li class='my-li-class'></li>
<div>
```

Next append won't be happening inside **li**

There are multiple ways you can do it,

Create a variable and append it to div.content.

```
var htmlData = "<li class='my-li-class'>" + 
    "<div class='imageclass'><img src='"+newData.img+"' class='innerimageclass'></div>" + 
    "<div class='another-inner-div'>" + 
    "<div class='main-title'>"+newData.title+"</div>" +
    "</div>" +  
    "</li>");
```

Or if you really want to make it really clean, use createElement and related function to created each element individually and finally add it to div.content.

Answer (score 0):

Please note: It is *significantly* faster to append multiple items as a single string, than to append multiple items one at a time. You need to rework your code to create a single HTML string and append once at the end.

e.g.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
    var html = "";
    $.each(data, function(n, newData) {
      html +=
        "<li class='my-li-class'>" + 
        "<div class='imageclass'><img src='"+newData.img+"' class='innerimageclass'></div>" + 
        "<div class='another-inner-div'>" + 
        "<div class='main-title'>"+newData.title+"</div>" +
        "</div>" +  
        "</li>");
    });
    $(".content").append(html);
});
```

or use `.html()`

```
$(".content").html(html);
```

As noted in comment, a `DIV` is not a valid child of a `UL`, so you need to target the `UL` instead:

```
$(".content").parent().append(html);
```

Or add a class to the UL instead and target that directly.

Comment: Please explain the downvote. This a) works and b) is a preferred way to do this in production and c) is different to the answers on the duplicate question.