# How do I update an Unordered List with values after a Live search in c# mvc code?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to do a live search to filter results as I type in the textbox. There is a html Unordered list that is populated from the model when the page is loading and those are the items I want to filter when searching. Problem is how do I update the ul with the search values?

The cshtml page:

```
<div>
  <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Sections">
  <ul id="menuList" style="max-height: 800px; overflow:scroll;">
      @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
         <li>
           <div style="display:inline-block; min-width:15%">@item.Index</div>
           <div style="display:inline; min-width:80%">@item.Title</div>
         </li>
        }
   </ul>
</div>
```

The ajax call:

```
$(function () {
            $("#search").keyup(function (e) {
                var s = $("#search").val();
                $.get("/Document/GetSearchItem?searchString=" + s, function (r) {
                    //how do I update ui with results here?
                    

                });
            });
        });
```

The controller method that query's the db and returns a list that I use to update the model, this works well.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSearchItem(string searchString)
        {
            var lst = await _sectionService.GetSearchString(searchString);
            var documentModel = new List<DocumentViewModel>();
            foreach (var item in lst)
            {
                documentModel.Add(new DocumentViewModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id.ToString(),
                    Title = item.Title,
                    Index = item.IndexNumber                    
                });
            }
            return View(documentModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{           
    return View();
}
  
public JsonResult Refresh(string search)
{               
    return Json(Records(search), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
 
private List<DocumentViewModel> Records(string search)
{
    var list = /* your code to obtain records */; 
    return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search)) ? list : list.Where(r => r.Title.StartsWith(search)).ToList();
}
```

The `Index.cshtml`:

```
@* 
  There is no data model here - the jQuery is working excellent for this example.
*@
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        Refresh();
    }

    function Refresh() {
        var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("Refresh", "Home")',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: { search },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#menuList').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#menuList').append('<li><div style="display:inline-block; min-width:15%">'
                        + data[i].Index + '</div>'
                        + '<div style="display:inline; min-width:80%">' + data[i].Title + '</div></li>'
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>

<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Sections" onkeyup="Refresh()">
        <ul id="menuList" style="max-height: 800px; overflow:scroll;">           
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, tweaked it a little bit but I was able to achieve desired output!

Comment: @purple: You are welcome! You can edit my answer and I will approve it. Perhaps it will help someone else too.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar kind of functioanlity in one of my asp.net projects and handled the ajax call this way. Check if it helps.

```
function SearchText() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "samplepage.aspx/samplemethod",
                    data: "{'searchValue':'" + document.getElementById('#search').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("No Match");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @siva, but any idea on how to append the data received on the success part of the ajax call to an unordered list?

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to use jQuery to do it manually.

Check this answer for some ideas: [How to add items to a unordered list <ul> using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208467/how-to-add-items-to-a-unordered-list-ul-using-jquery/1208505)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the li a dynamic id

```
<li id="li_@item.Index">
```

and in filter function hide all **li** items under **ul**,
then loop the result to show selected items